# React API call on each keystroke - issue with componentwillUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Setup**
I have an empty array of albums in my state in react when my component mounts.

**What am I doing**

On every input in my input box I make an API call which returns a list of albums, changing depending on the input. I want to add the albums to the array without mutating the old array. So, on each keystroke a new array should be created.

Also, and of more concern, as I cannot `setState` as this leads to an infinite loop, how should this be done? `ComponentWillReceiveProps` cannot be used either as it does not receive `props` on each key press/

```
class AlbumLookup extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            albumName: '',
            albums: []
        };

        this.updateAlbum = this.updateAlbum.bind(this);

  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

        axios.get('url', {
            params: { albumName: nextState.albumName}
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                albumName: [...response.data.items]
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }

  updateAlbum(value) {

    this.setState({
           album: value
       });

   }

   render() {

      const { album } = this.state;
      const { updateAlbum } = this;

      return (
         <label>Enter Album</label>
         <Input value={album} onChange={updateAlbum} />
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `componentWillUpdate` for this anyway, why not execute this within an `onChange` event handler?

Comment: what is this for? this.setState({ album: value }); it looks like you are not using this property.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly that looks like it could be a very valid point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple solution here.

Compare next `albumName` value with current value and only fetch when values don't match.

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.albumName !== nextState.albumName) {
        axios.get('url', {
            params: { albumName: nextState.albumName}
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                albumName: [...response.data.items]
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Gracias hombre!

Comment: You are welcome. Please, accept the answer, if found helpful ;)